# Range.Calculate not updating the values in range

Tags: excel, vba, calculation, named-ranges

I'm trying to use Excel VBA to recalculate a specific defined range without recalculating the rest of the worksheet.  Do you have a solution?

Note:

- The Active sheet is the sheet containing the defined range (i.e. Sheet1 or "Acronyms")
- The defined range is part of a table (i.e. "Tbl__Acronym_List[Matching Strength]")
- The Workbook Calculation Options is set to "Manual".
- I've reviewed the answers to other several similar posts, but they didn't seem to have a solution. (e.g. [angularjs - Input[type=range] value not updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37783375/angularjs-inputtype-range-value-not-updated))

Here's the code I currently have, that isn't working:

```
'-- Recalculate defined range "dr__show_match_strength".
     Range("dr__show_match_strength").Dirty
     Range("dr__show_match_strength").Calculate
```

Comment: Is `dr__show_match_strength` a named range?

Comment: Yes it is.  I did figure out the issue.  I thought I was recalculating "dr__Matching_Strength_Lookup_Fields", but I had coded in the wrong name.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the problem.  Simple mistake on my part.

The defined range that I was calculating (i.e. "dr__show_match_strength") wasn't the defined range that I thought it was.  I really wanted another range calculated (i.e. "dr__Matching_Strength_Lookup_Fields").

Code updated and verified as working:

```
        '-- Recalculate "Match Strength" information.
        Range("dr__Matching_Strength_Lookup_Fields").Dirty
        Range("dr__Matching_Strength_Lookup_Fields").Calculate
```